# How to retrieve a specific content from camel body to pass to a bean method in camel route?

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have a simple camel route defined which will consume an xml message.

The route is as follows:

```
from("from-endpoint").bean(myBean, "method1").log("$body")to("to-endpoint)
```

The bean definition is as follows:

```
class MyBean {
   public void method1(String value) {
      //so something with value
   }
}
```

Sample xml message is follows:

```
<name>
   <value>new value<value>
</name>
```

I would like to retrieve the value for attribute "value" and pass it to my bean method. I would like to do the retrieval of the attribute value in my route and keep my bean implementation clean of the references to the xml structure.  I also want to ensure that the route still propagates the original body and hence I do not wish to have a bean above which would extract the value from the XML and pass it downstream.

Hope that's clear.

Answer (score 2):

Before sending it to the bean you can set a header with the value:

```
.setHeader("value", xpath("/name/value/text()"))
```

and then

```
class MyBean  {
    public void method1(Exchange exchange) {
        System.out.println("MyBean - " + exchange.getIn().getHeader("value", String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I did not want to take as my bean now needs to have an understanding of the structure of the XML.  I would like to handle this within the route definition itself.  Please refer the last paragraph in my question.

Comment: i am getting The method xpath(String) is undefined , what would i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyBean implements Processor {
public void method1(Exchange exchange)throws Exception {

Foo foo = exchange.getIn().getBody(foo.class);
     value = foo.getvalue();
  //so something with value
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want perform any sort of XML function in the incoming payload then you can un-marshal your incoming payload using JAXB or XStream parsers, then you will have a POJO to work with instead of XML manipulation. Also in you route if you don't set anything in your exchange body then the payload remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

```java
class MyBean implements Processor {

    @override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        Foo foo = exchange.getIn().getBody(foo.class);
        value = foo.getvalue();
    }
}
```